# Different result query when use mysql and mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Here is my problem:

My database have table Book, Post. Each book has many post

Table *posts* has field '*book_id*', that is foreign key reference table Book primary key (id).

This is my index page. The idea is to get latest post from each book and order by published date.

When I code on localhost, every thing is OK. I can get latest post from each book and order by publish date. But when I deploy it in vps. It didn't get latest post, it get first post from each book. I didn't have any experience about it. Please help, thanks

On localhost, I use: Apache-2.2, PHP-5.3, Mysql-5.5, ENGINE type for table is InnoDB.

On VPS, I use: Nginx 1.7.6, PHP-FPM 5.5.18, MariaDB, ENGINE type for table is MyIsam

I guest the problem is InnoDB and MyIsam, I try to fix it. But, if you have free time, please give me some good advise. Thanks a lot

p/s: Sorry about my poor english

```
SELECT * FROM `my_book_store`.`books` 
AS `Book` 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM posts 
    WHERE posts.published = 1 AND posts.published_date <= NOW() 
    ORDER BY posts.published_date DESC
) AS `Post` 
ON (`Post`.`book_id` = `Book`.`id`) 
WHERE 1 = 1 
GROUP BY `Book`.`id` 
ORDER BY `Post`.`published_date` desc 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Its certainly not related to the `engine`. However if you want to get the latest post (last one added), there are other approach to do it which are much better.

Comment: The query itself is a problem, especially due to its ordered subquery. Each book should be joined to a post which is the latest one for that book, and the subquery should calculate the key of such post.

Comment: Thank a lot , Abhik Chakraborty and Dmitry Grekov  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.*, p.*  
FROM my_book_store.books AS b 
INNER JOIN posts p ON b.id = p.book_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT p.book_id, MAX(p.published_date) published_date
            FROM posts p 
            WHERE posts.published = 1 AND posts.published_date <= NOW() 
            GROUP BY p.book_id
          ) AS p1 ON p.book_id = p1.book_id AND p.published_date = p1.published_date 
GROUP BY b.id 
ORDER BY p.published_date DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Saharsh Shah. I got it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below queries which does the job of getting the last post from each book

```
select
b.id,
b.name,
p.content,
p.published_date
from book b 
join post p on p.book_id = b.id
left join post p1 on p1.book_id = p.book_id and p1.published_date > p.published_date
where p1.id is null;
```

OR

```
select 
b.id,
b.name,
p.content,
p.published_date
from book b 
join post p on p.book_id = b.id
where not exists(
  select 1 from post p1 
  where p.book_id = p1.book_id
  and p1.published_date > p.published_date
)
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b935a4/2)**

Comment: I love the first solution. In some circles, it's even named after me (albeit erroneously)!!, but it's not performative. The second solution uses a correlated subquery. Again, this is not performative. A better solution might use an uncorrelated subquery, as per the example provided in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you're only grouping by 
Book.id but select a lot of other non-aggregated values,
so actual query results depend on the execution plan the
optimizer came up with. See also

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can
>   refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause.
>   [...]
>   However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for
>   each group.
>
> **THE SERVER IS FREE TO CHOOSE ANY VALUE** from each
>   group, so unless     they are the same, the values chosen are
>   indeterminate.
>   Furthermore, the selection of values from each
>   group cannot be     influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause.

[Different result query when use mysql and mariadb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314820/different-result-query-when-use-mysql-and-mariadb)