# mysql select the latest 2 rows per category (minimum age difference from these 2 rows: 6hours)

Tags: mysql, select, grouping, rows

I got the following table

```
+----+---------------------+------------+-------+
| id | record_time         | price_date | price |
+----+---------------------+------------+-------+
| 1  | 2015-09-23 08:05:05 | 2015-09-29 | 100   |
| 2  | 2015-09-23 04:05:05 | 2015-09-29 | 101   |
| 3  | 2015-09-22 08:05:05 | 2015-09-29 | 102   |
| 4  | 2015-09-21 08:05:05 | 2015-09-29 | 103   |
| 5  | 2015-09-23 08:05:05 | 2015-09-30 | 104   |
| 6  | 2015-09-23 08:01:05 | 2015-09-30 | 105   |
| 7  | 2015-09-22 08:05:05 | 2015-09-30 | 106   |
+----+---------------------+------------+-------+
```

I would like to get the two latest **price_date** rows where however is minimum of 6 hours difference between these 2 rows regarding to **record_time**.

**Expected Result**

```
| 1 | 2015-09-23 08:05:05 | 2015-09-29 | 100
| 3 | 2015-09-22 08:05:05 | 2015-09-29 | 102
| 5 | 2015-09-23 08:05:05 | 2015-09-30 | 104
| 7 | 2015-09-22 08:05:05 | 2015-09-30 | 106
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
    SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        dt1.*
    FROM
        data_table dt1
    JOIN (SELECT 
        price_date
    FROM
        data_table
    GROUP BY price_date) dt2 ON (dt1.price_date = dt2.price_date)
    ORDER BY record_time DESC) dt
    GROUP BY price_date
    ORDER BY price_date) a UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        dt2.*
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        dt1.*
    FROM
        data_table dt1
    JOIN (SELECT 
        price_date
    FROM
        data_table
    GROUP BY price_date) dt2 ON (dt1.price_date = dt2.price_date)
    ORDER BY record_time DESC) dt
    GROUP BY price_date
    ORDER BY price_date) dt1
    JOIN (SELECT 
        dt1.*
    FROM
        data_table dt1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
        dt.id
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        dt1.*
    FROM
        data_table dt1
    JOIN (SELECT 
        price_date
    FROM
        data_table
    GROUP BY price_date) dt2 ON (dt1.price_date = dt2.price_date)
    ORDER BY record_time DESC) dt
    GROUP BY price_date) dt2 ON (dt1.id = dt2.id)
    WHERE
        dt2.id IS NULL
    ORDER BY price_date DESC) dt2 ON (dt1.price_date = dt2.price_date
        AND dt2.record_time < DATE_ADD(dt1.record_time, INTERVAL - 6 HOUR))
    ORDER BY dt2.record_time DESC) dt
    GROUP BY price_date) a) a
ORDER BY price_date ASC , record_time DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. However, it does NOT work :(
I am getting the last 4 price_dates in the table only (there is one entire year in the table), and the time difference and the latest 2 rows do also NOT work :( 

Any other idea?

Comment: @JOhnlw009a, what is your requirement? You had mentioned `get the two latest price_date rows` in your question. Do you need the result for each day?

Comment: Yes, 2 versions for each day (price_date), 1st: the latest version and 2nd: the version which is at least 6 hours or more older than the latest version (record_time).

Comment: You have 31 `price_date`s which has only single entry. Then how to get 2 versions for single day? `select * from (select count(id) count, price_date from data_table group by price_date) a where a.count < 2`

Comment: Well, please read my question. Your answer will NOT work at all. sqlfiddle: It's just a fraction of the table. The above example explains the problem quite well.

Comment: @JOhnlw009a, didn't want to give up! Hope the updated query helps!

Comment: Thanks, but is does NOT work. I uploaded your answer here, I see more than 2 price_date values '2015-09-13'. Any other ideas?

Comment: Easy to say does NOT work! Execute it in your fiddle and check. It returns only two rows for your given date. `7058 September, 12 2015 08:44:14 September, 13 2015 00:00:00 34
7037 September, 10 2015 08:42:28 September, 13 2015 00:00:00 36`

Comment: I get more than 2 values for 2015-09-13. It s totally mixed up with same rows in the result. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc778/2

Comment: Glad that the real data is in now! Please check the updated query.

Comment: Glad that the requirement is met! :)

Comment: I tried it on my maria DB server, I just get one 1 price_date instead of 2. At jsfiddle and on an old mysql server it works perfectly. I got all privileges as well. Any idea why I get 1 price_date only returned?

Comment: Why don't you try executing the query using a mysql client like workbench to validate?

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin or mysql shell. No errors occur. Just the executed result is being displayed, expect for the 1 price_date values instead of 2. Where is that error?

Comment: The column datatypes matches with what you created for sqlfiddle? If so, make sure about the 6 hours difference part. You may reduce that to 0 hour in the query to check for two rows.

Comment: Thats exactly the same table. I exported that table to an old mysql server where it works perfectly like on sqlfiddle though. Where is the problem at the maria DB server? That is really strange....

Comment: Different results when using mariadb vs. mysql? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314820/different-result-query-when-use-mysql-and-mariadb

Comment: "MariaDB has ignored the ORDER BY in the sub query"  Can we update that query above? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547108/different-results-in-sqlfiddle-com-5-5-30-and-mariadb-5-5-31 and 
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/

Comment: This - `THE SERVER IS FREE TO CHOOSE ANY VALUE from each group` could be the reason

Comment: What do you mean by that? An workaround due to "Why is ORDER BY in a FROM Subquery Ignored?"  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/  ...are you able to modify the query?

Comment: Somewhere to include "ORDER BY " -> "ORDER BY LIMIT 18446744073709551615" ...should to it..but where to include?

Comment: OK, got it now. I added to every sub query at the order by clause "LIMIT 18446744073709551615". Now it works with mariadb. Thanks a ton, James!!!

Comment: That's superb @JOhnlw009a!